# Improving performance of resolving a solitaire math-game

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

A bit of history:
Since I was a kid, I have been playing a very easy little solitaire game to which I have never found a solution and honestly, I don't know if there is one, but I would like to find it out with the help of my computer. First, let me explain the rules:

- First you have to take a grid sheet and draw an area of 10 x 10 squares.
- Next you have to place the first number at a square of your chioce (I usually use the square at 0,0)
- Now you have to start counting up numbers from 1 to 100 according to certain jump rules (I'll get into that right now) and annotating the corresponding number inside the square you are jumping to.
- Jump rules are: leave 2 squares blank horizontally or vertically and leave only one blank diagonally.

The problem:
I have written the following (awfully slow) code in Python. Considering that my interpretation is that the possiblities the computer has to explore are 100!, I think the "bruteforcing" method will take a pretty long time. I'm running an 11th gen I7 but my Python code gets only executed on a single core.

How could I speed my code up and/or how I could improve the algorithm?

Here is the code:

```
class Gametable:

    def __init__( self ):
        #This value contains the maximum number reched by the algorithm
        self.max_reached = 1

    def start_at( self, coordX,  coordY ):
        tmpTable = [
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
        ]
        #We do not need to check the first jump, since the table should be empty.
        if self.is_valid_move( coordX, coordY, 1, tmpTable ):
            print("Found a solution!")
        else:
            print("Found no solution :(")

    def print_table( self, table ):
        print(52*"-")
        for X in range(10):
            for Y in range(10):
                if table[ X ][ Y ] == 0:
                    print("|    ", end="")
                else:
                    print("| {:02d} ".format( table[ X ][ Y ]), end='')
            print(" |")
            print(52*"-")
        print()


    def is_valid_move( self,  X,  Y,  counter,  table):

        # Check bounds
        if  X < 0:
            return False
        elif  X > 9:
            return False
        elif  Y < 0:
            return False
        elif  Y > 9:
            return False

        # Now check next steps
        if  table[ X ][ Y ]==0:
                table[ X ][ Y ] = counter
                if self.is_valid_move( X + 3, Y, counter+1, table ) or self.is_valid_move( X - 3, Y, counter+1, table ) or self.is_valid_move( X , Y + 3, counter+1, table ) or self.is_valid_move( X,  Y - 3, counter+1, table ) or self.is_valid_move( X + 2, Y + 2, counter+1, table ) or self.is_valid_move( X + 2, Y - 2, counter+1, table ) or self.is_valid_move( X - 2, Y + 2, counter+1, table ) or self.is_valid_move( X - 2, Y - 2, counter+1, table ):
                    return True
                else:
                    if counter > self.max_reached:
                        print("Max reached "+str(self.max_reached))
                        self.print_table(table)
                        self.max_reached = counter
                    table[X][Y] = 0 # We'll have to delete the last step if there is no further possibility
                    return False

mytable = Gametable()
mytable.start_at( 0, 0 )
```

This is an example of the game:

[image: Game]

Comment: A couple of clarification questions: 1. you state you place the first number in a square of your choice, I assume the number placed there is 1 or can it be any number?  2. In your rules you state you leave two blank squares horizontally and vertically.  Must these squares be blank or do you just need to skip over them?  3.  Do you place numbers sequentially (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ....)?

Comment: 1. Yes, you start counting at 1, so the first number must be 1... but in a square of your choice. 2. no, they don't have to be blank, you have to skip them (i.e. "jump" over them).

Comment: 3. Yes, numbers have to be placed sequentially. I've added a picture where you can see the game dynamics. Watch from the first nuber (0,0) the algorithm goes vertically downwards leaving two squares empty each time. When it reaches the corner, it can't go any further so it does the same horizontally until it reaches the corner again. From there it jumps vertically upwards until it gets to the corner. Since there are no more movements to do horizontally nor vertically, it jumps diagonally, leaving one square empty. From there on, you may be able to follow the path the algorithm has taken.

Comment: Belongs on Code Review site

Comment: This problem looks like a variation of the classical Knights Tour problem.  Probably better classified as a Harmonic Path problem.  There are algorithmic approaches to solving such problems which will fare better than the brute force approach you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a go and implemented [Warnsdorff's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorff%27s_rule) for prioritising moves, and the program immediately found a solution:

```
def print_table(table):
    print(51*"-")
    for row in table:
        for cell in row:
            print(f"|{cell:>3} " if cell else "|    ", end='')
        print("|\n" + 51*"-")
    print()

def solve(table, x, y):
    sizey = len(table)
    sizex = len(table[0])
    size = sizey * sizex

    # Generate move list (nothing special)
    def moves(x, y):
        return [(x1, y1) 
            for x1, y1 in (
                (x + dx, y + dy)
                for dx, dy in (
                    (-3, 0), (-2,  2), (0,  3), ( 2,  2), 
                    ( 3, 0), ( 2, -2), (0, -3), (-2, -2)
                )
            )
            if 0 <= x1 < sizex and 0 <= y1 < sizey and table[y1][x1] == 0
        ]
 
    # Heuristic for evaluating a move by the number of followup moves
    def freedom(x, y):
        return len(moves(x, y))

    # Get move list sorted by heuristic (Warnsdorff's rule)
    def sortedmoves(x, y):
        return sorted((freedom(x1, y1), x1, y1) for x1, y1 in moves(x, y))

    def dfs(x, y, i):
        table[y][x] = i
        # Table completed?
        if i == size or any(dfs(x1, y1, i + 1) for _, x1, y1 in sortedmoves(x, y)):
            return True  # BINGO!
        table[y][x] = 0  # backtrack
        return False

    return dfs(x, y, 1)
    
table = [
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]

if solve(table, 0, 0):
    print("SOLVED!")
    print_table(table)
```

Output:

```
SOLVED!
---------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 43 | 67 | 16 | 42 | 75 | 31 | 39 | 74 | 32 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 69 | 18 |  3 | 83 | 35 |  4 | 82 | 36 |  5 | 81 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 66 | 15 | 41 | 76 | 94 | 40 | 73 | 93 | 30 | 38 |
---------------------------------------------------
|  2 | 44 | 68 | 17 | 79 | 86 | 34 | 80 | 87 | 33 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 70 | 19 | 95 | 84 | 72 | 96 | 89 | 37 |  6 | 92 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 65 | 14 | 57 | 77 | 99 | 56 | 78 |100 | 29 | 60 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 23 | 45 | 71 | 26 | 90 | 85 | 27 | 91 | 88 | 10 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 54 | 20 | 98 | 55 | 58 | 97 | 50 | 59 |  7 | 49 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 64 | 13 | 24 | 63 | 12 | 25 | 62 | 11 | 28 | 61 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 22 | 46 | 53 | 21 | 47 | 52 |  8 | 48 | 51 |  9 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

#### Other starting squares

When I tried other starting squares, it turned out that when starting at (4, 2) the search took too long. So I added a tie-breaker to the heuristic (in case the minimum freedom was shared by multiple moves): I went with the taxicab distance to the closest corner. This turned out to work out well for all starting positions:

```
def print_table(table):
    print(51*"-")
    for row in table:
        for cell in row:
            print(f"|{cell:>3} " if cell else "|    ", end='')
        print("|\n" + 51*"-")
    print()

def solve(table, x, y):
    sizey = len(table)
    sizex = len(table[0])
    size = sizey * sizex

    # Generate move list (nothing special)
    def moves(x, y):
        return [(x1, y1) 
            for x1, y1 in (
                (x + dx, y + dy)
                for dx, dy in (
                    (-3, 0), (-2,  2), (0,  3), ( 2,  2), 
                    ( 3, 0), ( 2, -2), (0, -3), (-2, -2)
                )
            )
            if 0 <= x1 < sizex and 0 <= y1 < sizey and table[y1][x1] == 0
        ]

    # Heuristic for evaluating a move by the number of followup moves
    def freedom(x, y):
        return len(moves(x, y))

    # Heuristic for breaking ties: taxicab distance to closest corner
    def cornerdistance(x, y):
        return min(x, sizex - 1 - x) + min(y, sizey - 1 - y),
    
    # Get move list sorted by heuristic (Warnsdorff's rule)
    def sortedmoves(x, y):
        return sorted((freedom(x1, y1), 
                       cornerdistance(x1, y1),
                       x1, y1) for x1, y1 in moves(x, y))

    def dfs(x, y, i):
        table[y][x] = i
        # Table completed?
        if i == size or any(dfs(x1, y1, i + 1) for _,_, x1, y1 in sortedmoves(x, y)):
            return True  # BINGO!
        table[y][x] = 0  # backtrack
        return False

    return dfs(x, y, 1)
    

# Try any starting square
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        table = [
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
        ]
        print("=====",i,j,"=================")
        if solve(table, i, j):
            print("SOLVED!")
            print_table(table)
```

All 100 solutions were spit out to the screen in no time.

Comment: Really interesting approach

Comment: Thak you very much for directing me in the right direction. I wasn't aware of that theorem. I'll have a deep look into it! That was a **great** and **friendly** solution... Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I have been fiddling a bit with the theory and the code and just for the sake of completion I'd like to share my code with all of you. There are probably more lines of comments than of code :D
I wanted to keep it recursive, for no particular reason, so after reading Wansdorff's theorem in it's original (german) form, I've come up with this:

```
class Gametable:
    """
        This class resolves a 10x10 board game
    """

    def __init__( self ): # Class constructor
        # Contains the maximum number reached by the algorithm
        self.max_reached = 1
        # Insert a newline, just for aesthetic reasons
        print()

    def start_at( self, X, Y ): # Entry point for the colculations. You choose where to start
        # Declare a temporary initialized game table
        tmpTable = [
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
        ]
        # We do not need to check the first jump, since the table should be empty.
        if self.is_valid_move( X, Y, 1, tmpTable ): # Start from the first cell
            print("     »  Found a solution from starting point ({:02d}, {:02d})  «".format(X,Y))
            print()
        else: # The search tree has finalized without a result ( not likely since we know there is a solution for every starting point of the board )
            print("Found no solution :(")

    def print_table( self, table ):
        """
            Method to print the found table to screen ( could be shorter, but I opted for the nicer looking table )
        """
        # Building blocks of the visually nicer table ╬ ╣ ╠ ╩ ╦ ║ ═ 
        print("     ╔════",end='')
        print(9*"╦════",end='')
        print("╗")
        for X in range(10):
            print("     ", end='')
            for Y in range(10):
                if table[ X ][ Y ] == 0:
                    print("║    ", end="")
                elif table[X][Y]==100:
                    print("║  ".format( table[ X ][ Y ]), end='')
                else:
                    print("║ {:02d} ".format( table[ X ][ Y ]), end='')
            print("║")
            if X < 9:
                print("     ╠════", end='')
                print(9*"╬════", end='')
                print("╣")
            else:
                print("     ╚════", end='')
                print(9*"╩════", end='')
                print("╝")

    def possible_move_count( self, X, Y, table ):
        """
            Counts the legally available moves from present position
        """
        # Reset the counter
        possible_moves = 0
        # Check and count vertical/horizontal moves
        if ( X > 2 ):
            if table[X-3][Y] == 0:
               possible_moves = possible_moves + 1
        if ( X < 7 ):
            if table[X+3][Y] == 0:
                possible_moves = possible_moves + 1
        if ( Y > 2 ):
            if table[X][Y-3] == 0:
                possible_moves = possible_moves + 1 
        if ( Y < 7 ):
            if table[X][Y+3] == 0:
                possible_moves = possible_moves + 1
        # Check and count diagonal moves
        if ( X > 1 ) and ( Y > 1 ):
             if table[X-2][Y-2] == 0:
                possible_moves = possible_moves + 1
        if ( X > 1 ) and ( Y < 8 ):
            if table[X-2][Y+2] == 0:
                possible_moves = possible_moves + 1
        if ( X < 8 ) and ( Y < 8 ):
            if table[X+2][Y+2] == 0:
                possible_moves = possible_moves + 1
        if ( X < 8 ) and ( Y > 1 ):
            if table[X+2][Y-2] == 0:
                possible_moves = possible_moves + 1
        return possible_moves
                
    def warnsdorff_move_matrix( self, X, Y, table ):
        """ Returns a matrix with n elements like so:
            [
                [ 1, ( 3,0 ) ]
                [ 2, ( -3,0 ) ]
                ...
                [ n, ( dx,dy ) ]
            ] where the first number represents the possible moves, and the second tuple, the move vector.
        """
        # Delcare an empty array
        move_array = []
        # Check and store horizontal/vertical legit move vectors
        if ( X > 2 ):
            move_array.append([ self.possible_move_count( X-3, Y, table ), [ -3, 0 ] ])
        if ( Y > 2 ):
            move_array.append([ self.possible_move_count( X, Y-3, table ), [ 0, -3 ] ])
        if ( X < 7 ):
            move_array.append([ self.possible_move_count( X+3, Y, table ), [ 3, 0 ] ])
        if ( Y < 7 ):
            move_array.append([ self.possible_move_count( X, Y+3, table ), [ 0, 3 ] ])
        # Check and store diagonal legit move vectors
        if ( X > 1 ) and ( Y > 1 ):
            move_array.append([ self.possible_move_count( X-2, Y-2, table ), [ -2, -2 ] ])
        if ( X < 8 ) and ( Y < 8 ):
            move_array.append([ self.possible_move_count( X+2, Y+2, table ), [ 2, 2 ] ])
        if ( X > 1 ) and ( Y < 8 ):
            move_array.append([ self.possible_move_count( X-2, Y+2, table ), [ -2, 2 ] ])
        if ( X < 8 ) and ( Y > 1 ):
            move_array.append([ self.possible_move_count( X+2, Y-2, table ), [ 2, -2 ] ])
        # Return the array sorted from least to most possible move vectors 
        return sorted(move_array)

    def is_valid_move( self,  X,  Y,  counter,  table ):
        """
            Check if a move is valid.
            This function is recursive. We have two base cases:
            · Function returns false if either it is out of bounds or there are no more moves available
            · Function returns true if 100 is reached.
            The rest of the cases return the result of the next move.
        """
        # Check bounds ( base case )
        if ( X < 0 ) or ( X > 9 ) or ( Y < 0 ) or ( Y > 9):
            return False
        else: # ...or putting it the other way 'round: coordinates are whithin bounds.
            if table[X][Y] == 0:
                table[X][Y] = counter
                if counter == 100: # ( base case )
                    self.print_table(table)
                    return True # This is not neccessarily THE solution but ONE solution.
                move_array = self.warnsdorff_move_matrix( X, Y, table )
                for move in move_array:
                    if self.is_valid_move( X+move[1][0], Y+move[1][1], counter+1, table ):
                        return True # ( Recursion )
            else:
                return False # ( base case )

# Start main program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Instantiate Class
    myTable = Gametable()
    # Provide a starting coordinate
    myTable.start_at( 0, 0 )
```

Best regards